# How to convert string to ECS/P Hex

Tags: jquery, string, type-conversion, hex

I'm using jquery / javascript to print raw data to a network label printer. In order to do that the strings will need to be converted to hexadecimal. with a `\x` preceding each character.

SO if I wanted to print a label with "**I love stackoverflow**" the string would need to be converted to `\x49\x20\x6C\x6F\x76\x65\x20\x73\x74\x61\x63\x6B\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x66\x6C\x6F\x77`.

I have searched around and I can't find anything on this. Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

I could create a library of variables for each character `var A = '/x41;` and then run the string through a 'checker' that goes through the entire sting, but I feel like I am missing a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it this way:

- [...str]: convert the string to an array of chars
- .map(): apply a function on each char
- convert a char to integer --> to hex number
- join the array: get the hex string

```js
function stringtohex(str) {
  return  [...str].map(e => '\\x' + Number(e.charCodeAt(0)).toString(16)).join('')
}

var convertedstr = stringtohex( "I love stackoverflow");

console.log(convertedstr);
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant, but for some reason instead of printing the text it is printing out the converted string.